# Finding impulse response of the block diagram

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have the following [block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4sxo.png) and each [subsystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtH1O.png), I need to find the overall impulse response for 0<=n<=99.

The individual impulse response for each subsystem was found as shown.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n1 = np.arange(0, 6, 1) # set upper limit = 5 and lower limit = 0 in steps of 1.
h1 = [1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32] #impulse response h1
plt.stem(n1, h1)
n2 = np.arange(0, 6, 1) # set upper limit = 5 and lower limit = 0 in steps of 1.
h2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] #impulse response h2
plt.stem(n2, h2)
n3 = np.arange(0, 6, 1) # set upper limit = 5 and lower limit = 0 in steps of 1.
h3 = [1/4, 1/2, 1/3, 0, 0, 0] #impulse response h3
plt.stem(n3, h3)
```

Then I performed the following convolution and addition to find overall impulse response:

```
h_t = np.convolve(h1,h2, 'full') + h3
```

but I got the following error.

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (6,)
```

Not certain how I should incorporate the range of n values considered.

Comment: It's complaining because `h3` isn't the same length as the array you're adding it to.  You just need to add 5 zeros to `h3`

Comment: Ok I did that however, what about the 0<=n<=99 range? As I am not understanding the actual use of it because for values of n>=11 the amplitude of the impulse response is going to be 0

Comment: The impulse response can be extended in time to infinity if you pad with zeros. It is conceptually the same impulse response. But for numpy, you need to have arrays aligned before you can add them.

Comment: Yes, it's odd that you would be asked for impulse responses out to 99 when the subsystems are so short.  It's also a little odd that you were given the subsystems in a different notation.  I suggest rereading the question to make sure you understand the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pad the various impulse responses so that they match in shape. In effect, the impulse responses you show are just the non-zero values. After that, you can pad to infinity time with zero.

```py
def pad(y, t):
    return np.pad(y, (0, len(t) - len(y)), constant_values=0)

t = np.arange(20)  # or change to 100 for 0<=n<=99, but that's lots of zeros...
h1 = [1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32]  # impulse response h1
h2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  # impulse response h2
h3 = [1/4, 1/2, 1/3]  # impulse response h3
h_t = pad(np.convolve(h1, h2, 'full'), t) + pad(h3, t)


# or, equivalently:

t = np.arange(20)
h1 = pad([1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32], t)  # impulse response h1
h2 = pad([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], t)  # impulse response h2
h3 = pad([1/4, 1/2, 1/3], t)  # impulse response h3
h_t = np.convolve(h1, h2, 'full')[:len(t)] + h3


plt.stem(t, pad(h1, t), markerfmt='C0o')
plt.stem(t, pad(h2, t), markerfmt='C1o')
plt.stem(t, pad(h3, t), markerfmt='C2o')
plt.stem(t, h_t, markerfmt='C3-')
```

[image]

**Addendum**

To address the case where `y` is longer than what we need, a modified function can clip or pad depending on the need:

```py
def take(y, n):
    y = y[:n]
    return np.pad(y, (0, n - len(y)), constant_values=0)
```

Examples:

```py
n = 20
t = np.arange(n)
h1 = take([1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32], n)  # impulse response h1
h2 = take([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], n)  # impulse response h2
h3 = take([1/4, 1/2, 1/3], n)  # impulse response h3
h_t = take(np.convolve(h1, h2, 'full'), n) + h3
```

And also:

```py
X = take(np.exp(-t/10), n)
h_t = take(np.convolve(h1, X, 'full'), n) + h3
```

Comment: Thank you I was not considering padding beforehand. If you do not mind I have a follow up query as I was using your pad function to compute the output `y[n]` by doing a convolution between `h_t` and `X` where `X = np.exp(-N/10);` (N consists of the first 10 samples). The following: `y_n = pad(np.convolve(h_t, X, 'full'), t)` provided this error `ValueError: index can't contain negative values` Why is the pad fn not working the way I expect it to?

Comment: sure -- see addendum in the edited answer.